# Why can't I comment on a module' project page on drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

I can't comment on the project page https://drupal.org/project/awssdk

Why is it so?

The module seems to work with long out-dated AWS SDK for PHP 1.6.2 so I just want to make a comment there to suggest the contributors to update the module and the documentation.

Comment: A downvote without any comment? Can somebody please enlighten me why I got the downvote?

Comment: For that you need to create support request in that module's issue queue.

Comment: Thanks, @Mathankumar but I can comment on other modules' project pages, why not this particular one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Drupal.org, you cannot comment on any project page, as the comments are disabled for every node of the *project* content type.

These are the comment settings for that project page. (I am a Drupal.org webmaster; what I see when editing a node edit page is not what normal users see.)

[image: screenshot]

If you see any project page with the comments enabled, please report it on the [Drupal.org webmasters queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/webmasters), and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The project page of the module you've mentioned or any other module/theme/distribution is meant only have a brief description, and releases of that particular project.

If you need to contact any of the maintainer of the project, you should use the *issue queue* of the project which could be found at : `https://drupal.org/project/issues/{project_name}` just replace `{project_name}` with the project name, in your case *awssdk*.

Detailed reading here : [Use the issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/317).

And if you feel that the project is not being updated / supported for quite some time and the bugs aren't being fixed, and you intend to fix them you have an option to take over the maintainership of the project.

More reading here : [Dealing with unsupported (abandoned) projects](https://drupal.org/node/251466).

Comment: thank you, it's a pity I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer up yet